# ¿Es Crystal Reports grautito?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports, licencias

Debo implementar algún sistema de reportes en dos aplicaciones, y mi idea es usar [**Crystal Reports**](http://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/)

Buscando, no encontré temas referidos a la licencia, y me genera la duda, es gratis implementarlo en mis aplicaciones?

Lo usaría, tanto en una aplicación wpf y también en otra asp mvc funcionando en un servidor

Comment: Yo nunca he llegado a saberlo exactamente, pero [aqui tienes un documento](http://www.dataaccess.com/KBasePublic/Files/2463.CR_Licensing.pdf) donde supuestamente lo explican.

Comment: Existe una versión gratuita y una de paga, obvi la de paga tiene más características pero la gratuita te funciona bien

Comment: @shop350 pero la gratuita es gratuita en todos los ámbitos? Encontre un documento similar al que dejo Pikoh un poco mas nuevo que dice que si es una aplicación redistribuida y server side, era obligatoria la compra de licencias

Comment: Sí mira, existe el instalable para el Visual Studio, el cual te pone más cosas debido a que desarrollaras, y existe el instalable del runtime, osea sólo lo que necesita el cliente, revisa esta página... https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

Comment: Encontre la respuesta definitiva en el [una respuesta](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3764004) dentro del foro de sap El único caso en el que **NO** es gratuito, es en la redistribución de aplicaciones que corran en el servidor.

Comment: ¿Y qué tiene que ver con C# esta pregunta?

Comment: [SAP Compro Crystal Reports](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports), ahora ellos son quienes desarrollan/venden este producto. Puedes ver más detalles (sobre licenciamiento y precios) en : [SAP Crystal Reports](https://www.crystalreports.com/)